# Laravel redirect user to core auth login page when i directly access to guard login page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

I have made a multiple login laravel application for which i have used laravel guards and provider concept.Now i am facing an issue which is 
Suppose i have a writer user whose route are grouped if i want to direct access any route of the writer users without login then it redirects me to auth login page.

My point is that i want to redirect user to relevant login page if someone  direct access to writer user routes it should be redirected to writer user login page instead of auth login page

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code what have you tired so far?

Comment: Salman Zafar can you give me any idea about this if you get my point which i have asked

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called `Laravel Middlewares`. A practical use case for such is the `auth` middleware, which is applied to prevent anyone who isn't an authenticated user from accessing sensitive pages. Learn more about middlewares [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware).

Comment: can you give me an idea about the logic in construct method that if a specific group route is directly access then i should redirect the user to that user login page for example if a user access writer user routes directly then it should be redirect to write user login page instead of auth login page ... can i achieve this within the construct method if you have the logic for that then please share it with me